# Cover div with child after child rotation

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing an image, I want to rotate the image. After rotation the image should cover the parent div, overflow would be hidden. I have two pictures of what I get and what I want (lack of reputation doesn't allow me to embed the pictures):

[image]

[image]

```
.parent {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    max-width:480px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.background{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.grafic {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    max-height:360px;
    height:auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

<div class="parent">
    <img class="grafic" alt="" src="img.gif"
    <img class="background" src="gfx/missingpicture.gif">
</div>
```

As you can see, I can rotate the image, but the image isn't fully covering the parent div. I couldn't find anything to this exact problem.

Some thoughts:
One could use JQuery to calculate the necessary height/width to cover the parent div, but I hate using JS/JQuery if a pure CSS solution is possible (I can do a JS solution by myself, but I still suck at CSS).
I use PHP (I'll know the degree), so precalculating stuff can be done, but the parent div becomes smaller on smaller screens. A fix width would kinda suck then..

Comment: You can use a percentage width for the chlid e.g. 150%. When the factor stays the same this would be possible

Comment: Could you not just scale the image?

Comment: @Fuzzyma I tried scaling it up by setting the width to 200% or whatever, but nothing happened. I assume I have some kind of problem in my css: In Firebug it says width:480px, but when I open the width-tab-thing, it lists mystyle.css with 1000% width (what I used) as source.

Comment: I was stupid, some other stylesheet added a max-width. Meh.
I still have no clue on how to so the needed math.

Comment: @Lutan Did you check my answer?

Comment: @Dura I'm currently at work, I'll test it once I'm at home. A coworker had also a cool idea, I will make an update once I found a working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of CSS-only solution, so here's something with JS that I've used before.

You don't need to do the maths yourself in order to get the dimensions of your transformed object.

Instead you can use the [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) method which returns the `height` and `width` of the element *after* the transformation.

Once you have the dimensions, it should be easy to adapt the parent dimensions to fit the rotated image.

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x5Qgx/50/).

Also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393227/jquery-rotate-image-and-adjust-the-parent-element-accordingly) has [working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/pnp1kyjh/1/) which does what you want.

I hope it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I do not required reputation for posting a comment so I am posting as a comment. I am only addressing the sizing options for the image.

Say your image has width=w and height=h. Then if the size of the outer quadrilateral will have size

```
sqrt(w*w + h*h)
```

. Please note that the outer image will not be a square if inner image is not a square.